# VB.Net - Excel application get showing values of an range

Tags: arrays, vb.net, visual-studio, excel, range

I'm trying get an Excel Range and copy into an array of objects with Vb.Net.

This is not a problem. I use the following code:

```
Dim vValues(,) As Object = ExcelApp.Range(vRange).Value
```

And works fine; but I have a the following case:

[image: Excel]

In the column "C"; the value has a specific format and internally has another value.

My question is:

Somebody know the way to get the information exact as the user see?

I'm trying to get the information without use a `For ... Each` or some kind of cycle.

I'm also tried to avoid use "text to columns" function.

Both seems right solutions, but would impact the performance with a lot of data.

FYI: Also I can get the information through the ODBC connection; but I'm searching the solution using a Range

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exactly what the user sees is the `Text` property. But you cannot have an array of that, you will have to query each cell individually.

You are getting a `Double` value in your array instead of a `DateTime` value because you have "Time" formatting applied in Excel. If you had a format from the "Date" category, Excel would instead send a proper `Variant/Date`, not a `Double` that represents it.

Another option would be [constructing the `DateTime` objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.fromoadate.aspx) on the .NET side, provided you know in which columns they should be.

Comment: Exactly. In any case; I want create a generic method to take a Excel Range and transformed into a DataTable; then, I don't want evaluate these case of exceptions.

I think that the best approach it's transform all columns to text, using "Text to columns" functionality